# Prove that $f^{-1}$ is not invertible in $f(a)$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$  be a bijective correspondence of class $C^1$. Let $a \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $Df(a)$ is not an isomorphism. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is not invertible at $f(a)$.

*Proof* : Suppose that $f^{-1}$ is invertible at $w := f(a)$. Then, by the chain rule, as $f^{-1}\circ f= \operatorname{Id}$, then
$$D(\operatorname{Id})(a) = Df^{-1}(f(a))Df(a),$$
so $\det Df(a) \neq 0$ and $Df(a)$ is an isomorphism, which is a contradiction.

My question is,  if the function is biunivocally determined, does that not guarantee that the inverse of the inverse exists?

Comment: By "biunivoca", do you mean what we call in English bijective (one-to-one and onto)?

Comment: It  it Italian with English accent or English with Italian accent?

Comment: yes ............... (one-to-one and onto)

Comment: @weymarandres I think it means that a local differentiable inverse or continuous inverse.